# DotNetZip - [wildcard.png]

Tags: wildcard, dotnetzip

Can you extract on a wildcard?

I can see that you can when zipping up files? I will not know the name of the files within the zipped folder, however the type will always be .png and there will only ever be one png file.

i.e.

```
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                var entry = zipout["*.png"];

                                if (entry != null)
                                {
                                    entry.Extract(ms);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                        using (var zipout = ZipFile.Read(stream))
                        {
                            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                foreach (var e in zipout.Where(e => e.FileName.Contains(".png")))
                                {
                                    e.Extract(ms);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```